# Efficient way to edit the last line of a text file in Python

Tags: python, sql, replace

I have a Python script which creates a large SQL insert file of about 300,000 lines. The problem with this is that the last line of the file ends up looking like this:

```
'),
```

Which results in a SQL error as it is expecting a closing semicolon.

I am looking for an efficient way to open the file to replace the comma with a semicolon on the last line.

Comment: Define 'efficient'. Time, CPU, memory efficient? Can't the Python script be altered to not emit that comma?

Comment: Your could seek to a character before end-of-file, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html.  But it would be better to fix the original script which creates the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `file.seek` which is built into the standard library. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek

You simply need to set offset to 0 and the whence to `os.SEEK_END`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this neat solution which did exactly what I needed:

```
# Get the last line in the file and replace the comma with a semicolon to close the SQL statement.
with open(file_to_execute, 'rb+') as filehandle:
    filehandle.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    filehandle.truncate()
    filehandle.write(";")
    filehandle.close()
```

---

*This was originally added to [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35125295/2) of the question.*