# Python: Replace last line in text file

Tags: python

I have been struggling with python script to replace last line in a text file.

I have tried several Answers example:

[how-do-i-modify-the-last-line-of-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327985/how-do-i-modify-the-last-line-of-a-file)

[efficient-way-to-edit-the-last-line-of-a-text-file-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125295/efficient-way-to-edit-the-last-line-of-a-text-file-in-python)

None of that worked

I am using Python 3.10

All I need is to python overwrite last line of text file example

```
line1
line2
line3
lastline
```

to be overwritten to

```
line1
line2
line3
overwritten_lastline
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Please explain more about what you mean by "none of that worked". Surely reading all lines of the file into a list, replacing the last element of the list, and writing all elements of the list as lines to a new file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328196) will work.

Comment: @mkrieger1 exactly seek(-len(os.linesep), os.SEEK_END) did not worked and I got error

Comment: That's not what the answer I was referring to suggests to do (it's another answer). But it should still work. If you don't tell us the exact code you used and the error message you got, we can't explain to you what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open('example.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()[:-1]
lines.append("YOUR NEW LINE")
file.close()
file = open('example.txt','w')
file.writelines(lines)
```

It cannot be more simpler than replacing one by one all the lines. Here's my answer that has just worked for me.